# Will a spinning pencil end over end then landing on its eraser bounce higher than a pencil dropped without spinning landing on its eraser?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

This is a question about conservation of momentum. Will the inertia of the rotating pencil make the pencil bounce higher? Both cases the pencil is dropped from the same height but the spinning pencil is made to spin by a force couple besides being dropped.

Comment: Momentum is not conserved when bouncing on the ground.  If the eraser is considered elastic, then energy is conserved during the bounce.  A rotating pencil has both translational $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and rotational $\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$ kinetic energy.  How will the pencil be oriented when it hits the ground?

Comment: Ken Mellendorf Consider the eraser elastic. When the eraser hits the ground in the case of not rotating the pencil is perpendicular to the ground. In the case of the pencil rotating the pencil is at 60 degrees to the ground. Also consider it a 2D problem.

Comment: Shouldn't momentum always be conserved? What is different about bouncing on the ground? I've seen a video where a similar experiment was done in space and a slow moving stick that was spinning struck a surface and stopped spinning while bouncing away very quickly.

Comment: https://youtube.com/shorts/MXVwJszAIlw?feature=share

Comment: Momentum is conserved when you include the Earth as part of the system.  Momentum is a vector, so momentum changes when down momentum becomes up momentum.  The Earth's momentum also changes to compensate.  When a piece of clay hits a building, the momentum of the clay becomes zero, but the momentum passes into the building.  The building is so massive that you don't see it.  mV becomes Mv.  The wind affects the building much more than does a ball of clay.  Changes in air pressure affect the ground more than does a pencil.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do this experiment yourself? You don't need any special equipment: just a pencil, some time, and maybe a camera.

The short answer is: probably, but maybe not, depending on the angle of impact. If the pencil is spinning, it will likely bounce higher, because of two reasons: (1) a spinning pencil is more likely to strike the ground at an angle that favors energy conversion from rotation to translation than the other way around, and (2) if there is energy conversion from rotation to translation, a pencil spinning fast means lots of rotational kinetic energy, and thus more energy converted to translation.

[image]

Let's start with point 1 because it requires fewer assumptions and not much math. Referring to the figure above, if $\theta > 0$, the impulse $\vec J$ that the ground exerts on the pencil will generally oppose the counterclockwise rotation, facilitating a conversion of rotational kinetic energy to translational kinetic energy. On the other hand, if $\theta < 0$, the impact will tend to cause the pencil to spin faster. The higher the angular speed $\omega$, the more likely it is for the pencil to strike the ground with $\theta > 0$. This might already be obvious if you try to visualize the pencil rotating counterclockwise as it falls, but it can also be shown that if the initial orientation of the pencil is random, the probability that $\theta > 0$ is about
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{2R\omega}{\pi |v_y|}\right)$$
where $v_y$ is the velocity of the center of mass just before impact and $R$ is half the length of the pencil. This expression is valid when $R\omega$ is small compared to $|v_y|$.

Now for point 2, without doing the experiment, a precise quantitative answer isn't simple, because modeling the impact process isn't necessarily straightforward. In general the results will depend on the shape of the colliding object, the material it is made of, its orientation when it hits the ground, and the translation/angular velocities just before impact. But here I will make an attempt.

Given the pre-impact center of mass velocity $\vec v$ and angular speed $\omega$, we are trying to find the post-impact velocity $\vec v'$ and angular speed $\omega'$. The first equation is obtained by assuming the impact occurs roughly at a single point on the pencil, so the impulse $\vec J$ imparts no torque on the pencil about the point of impact, and angular momentum about this point is conserved:
$$v_y \sin(\theta) - v_x \cos(\theta) + \gamma R\omega = v_y' \sin(\theta) - v_x' \cos(\theta) + \gamma R\omega' \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where the moment of inertia of the pencil about its center of mass is $\gamma m R^2=\frac{1}{3}mR^2$ (i.e. $\gamma = 1/3$).

As a simple impact model, we will assume some normal and tangential coefficients of restitution, defined as
$$e_y = -\frac{u_y'}{u_y} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
$$e_x = -\frac{u_x'}{u_x} \tag{3}\label{3}$$
where $\vec u$ and $\vec u'$ are the velocities of the end of the pencil hitting the ground just before and just after the collision, respectively. I caution again that in general the coefficients of restitution could depend on the many factors mentioned above and are not universal constants. We can write
$$u_x = v_x + \cos (\theta)R\omega$$
$$u_y = v_y - \sin (\theta)R\omega$$
The equations for the post-impact velocities are similar.

The maximum height the pencil's center of mass achieves is $v_y'^2/2g$, so $v_y'$ is the quantity of interest. With \eqref{1}-\eqref{3}, we have the equations needed to solve for $v_x'$, $v_y'$ and $\omega'$. Since these equations describe a system of equations that are linear on all velocity components and angular speeds, $v_y'$ is linear in $v_x$, $v_y$ and $\omega$. This means that as long as $\frac{dv_y'}{d\omega} > 0$, you can make $v_y'$ as high as needed by spinning the pencil faster, without changing the initial vertical velocity $v_y$. The figure below shows that for all $\theta > 0$ and coefficients of restitution $e_x = e_y = e$, $\frac{dv_y'}{d\omega} > 0$. You can make the pencil jump as high as you want by spinning it fast enough, provided $\theta > 0$.

I should mention that the figure below is potentially misleading because even though the x-axis includes all angles $-90^\circ \le \theta \le 90^\circ$, not all angles are actually possible if the pencil is spinning fast enough. In particular, if $\omega$ is very high, the pencil will always land on a flat surface with a small $|\theta|$.

[image]

Finally, for a more direct answer to your question, we can plot $v_y'$ for different $\theta$ and $\omega$ (here I assume $e_x = e_y = 0.8$). We see that for $\theta > 0$, all curves with non-zero $\omega$ have higher $v_y'$ than for $\omega = 0$, but the opposite is true for $\theta < 0$. So the answer is: a spinning pencil jumps higher relative to a non-spinning one for $\theta > 0$ but lower for $\theta < 0$, assuming the angles of impact are the same for both pencils. But remember that $\theta > 0$ is more likely, so a spinning pencil will probably jump higher if its initial orientation is random. In fact, as you can see below, the range of possible $\theta < 0$ becomes quite narrow for high $\omega$.

[image]

Comment: Very satisfactory. There's a much simpler experiment to show the relationship between Vy and omega before and after a collision. It is to simply place a pencil over the edge of a table and strike it with a finger near the end hanging over the edge from underneath. The pencil will fly straight up and rotate end over end. In this experiment it is seen that the force or impulse of the striking finger roughly separates into Vy' and Omega' as your first equation describes. ie Vy' is less and Omega' is greater. Then it follows that the reverse applies where the rotation slows the velocity increases.

Comment: @JohnTrainor Thanks. Be sure to post your results as an answer if you do carry out such an experiment.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

lets obtain the center of mass velocities $~v_1~$ and $~v_2~$ after the pencil collied with the floor . in both cases the momenta and the energies are conserved. the heights after the collision are proportional to the velocities of the CM after the collision .

**case I**

$$v_1=\sqrt{2\,g\,h_1}$$

**case II**

$$ v_2=\frac{u_2\,I_z}{I_z+ m\,\rho^2}$$

where $~u_2~$ is the center of mass velocity bevor the collision ,$~I_z~$ pencil inertia and m the pencil mass .

with $~u_2\approx~v_1$

$$ v_2=\frac{v_1\,I_z}{I_z+ m\,\rho^2}< v_1$$

> Will the inertia of the rotating pencil make the pencil bounce higher?

no because $~v_2 < ~v_1$

Comment: I don't see it for case II. Intuitively angular velocity should decrease while velocity at cm increases. Iz is much greater in case II than case I. The normal force seems it could be thought of the same as a particle collision with a rod on a frictionless surface.